# Rails video_tag in Bootstrap Link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm pretty new to rails and coding generally, but I'm trying to write something in my view that says, if there is a video in connection with a proposal, a link should be shown to that video (on you tube). If there isn't a video, then a notice confirming there is no video is displayed.  I have a boolean in my schema for video_proposal, if it's true, then I want to show the link to the video.

I think I'm not combining the bootstrap with the rails properly. I'm not sure whether the problem is the way that I have referenced the video_tag inside the button.

I've done the following:

```
<% if @project.video_proposal %>
             <button type="button" <%= video_tag "@project.link_to_video_proposal" %> class="btn btn-link"> More about the project </button>

            <% else %>
              <p>No video recorded</p> 
            <% end %>
```

Does anyone know how to use a video_tag in this way? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy-pasting from [Bootstrap's responsive embed element](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)...

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Is your .link_to_video_proposal a string? If so, is there a reason you can't...?

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="<%= @project.link_to_video_proposal %>"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Lanny, thanks very much. I'll try those. I was trying to get the string (link to the youtube clip) styled as a link button, but I hadn't come across the embed that you've suggested. Thanks very much again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if @project.video_proposal %>
   <%= video_tag @project.link_to_video_proposal %>More about the project
<% else %>
   <p>No video recorded</p> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi Ajay, Thanks for the help with the rails part. I can't see how that brings in the bootstrap styling.

Comment: have you created a div class for the video container?

Comment: Hi Emma, I have got a div class, I'm trying to figure out how to use bootstrap's link styling on the link.